# Single ScheduledExecutorService instance vs Multiple ScheduledExecutorService instances

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, scheduled-tasks

I have a service which schedules async tasks using ScheduledExecutorService for the user. Each user will trigger the service to schedule two tasks. (The 1st Task schedule the 2nd task with a fixed delay, such as 10 seconds interval)
pseudocode code illustration:

```
task1Future = threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(task1);
for(int i = 0; i< 10000; ++i) {
    task2Future = threadPoolTaskScheduler.schedule(task2);
    task2Future.get(); // Takes long time
    Thread.sleep(10);
}

task1.Future.get();
```

Suppose I have a potential of 10000 users using the service at the same time, we can have two kinds of ScheduledExecutorService configuration for my service:

1. A single ScheduledExecutorService for all the users.
2. Create a ScheduledExecutorService for each user.

What I can think about the first method:

Pros:

1. Easy to control the number of threads in the thread pool.
2. Avoid creating new threads for scheduled tasks.

Cons:

1. Always keeping multiple number of threads available could waste computer resources.
2. May cause the hang of the service because of lacking available threads. (For example, set the thread pool size to 10, and then there is a 100 person using the service the same time, then after entering the 1st task and it tries to schedule the 2nd task, then finding out there is no thread available for scheduling the 2nd task)

What I can think about the second method

Pros:

1. Avoiding always keep many threads available when the number of user is small.
2. Can always provide threads for a large number of simultaneously usage.

Cons:

1. Creating new threads creates overheads.
2. Don't know how to control the number of maximum threads for the service. May cause the RAM out of space.

Any ideas about which way is better?

Comment: Don't do either. Create a `TaskScheduler` with Spring and use that. You could even create 2 which use each other (a smaller one for task 1 as that looks like a simple task and quick a second one with maybe a bit larger pool to handle the tasks). Or just use `@Async` on the second task to have it handled by a `TaskExecutor`.

Comment: Thanks! I do use ThreadPoolTaskScheduler in spring, but since it delegates the work to ScheduledExecutorService, then I wrote that directly in the question. By the way, I updated the post with code illustration.

Answer (score 1):

## Single `ScheduledExecutorService` drives many tasks

The entire point of a `ScheduledExecutorService` is to maintain a collection of tasks to be executed after a certain amount of time elapses.

So given the scenario you describe, you need only a single `ScheduledExecutorService` object. Submit your 10,000 tasks to that one object. Each task will be executed approximately when its designated delay elapses. Simple, and easy.

## Thread pool size

The real issue is deciding how many threads to assign to the `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Threads, as currently implemented in the [OpenJDK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project, are mapped directly to host OS threads. This makes them relatively heavyweight in terms of CPU and memory usage. In other words, currently Java threads are “expensive”.

There is no simple easy answer to calculating thread pool size. The optimal number is the least amount of threads that can keep up with the workload without over-burdening the host machine’s limited number of cores and limited memory. If you search Stack Overflow, you’ll find many discussions on the topic of deciding how many threads to use in a pool.

## *Project Loom*

And keep tabs with the progress of [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) and its promise to bring [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277131) to Java. That technology has the potential to radically alter the calculus of deciding thread pool size. Virtual threads will be more efficient with CPU and with memory. In other words, virtual threads will be quite “cheap”, “inexpensive”.

## How executor service works

You said:

> entering the 1st task and it tries to schedule the 2nd task, then finding out there is no thread available for scheduling the 2nd task

That is not how the scheduled executor service (SES) works.

If a task being currently executed by a SES needs to schedule itself or some other task to later execution, that submitted task is added to the queue maintained internally by the SES. There is no need to have a thread immediately available. Nothing happens immediately except that queue addition. Later, when the added task’s specified delay has elapsed, the SES looks for an available thread in its thread-pool to execute that task that was queued a while back in time.

You seem to feel a need to manage the time of each task’s execution on certain threads. But that is the job of the scheduled executor service. The SES tracks the tasks submitted for execution, notices when their specified delay elapses, and schedules their execution on a thread from its managed pool of threads. You don’t need to manage any of that. Your only challenge is to assign an appropriate number of threads to the pool.

## Multiple executor services

You commented:

> why don't use multiple ScheduledExecutorService instances

Because in your scenario, there is no benefit. Your Question implies that you have many tasks all similar with none being prioritized. In such a case, just use one executor service. One scheduled executor service with 12 threads will get the same amount of work accomplished as 3 services with 4 threads each.

As for excess threads, they are not a burden. Any thread without a task to execute uses virtually no CPU time. A pool may or may not choose to close some unused threads after a while. But such a policy is up to the implementation of the thread pool of the executor service, and is transparent to us as calling programmers.

If the scenario were different, where some of the tasks block for long periods of time, or where you need to prioritize certain tasks, then you may want to segregate those into a separate executor service.

In today's Java (before Project Loom with virtual threads), when code in a thread blocks, that thread sits there doing nothing but waiting to unblock. Blocking means your code is performing an operation that awaits a response. For example, making network calls to a socket or web service blocks, writing to storage blocks, and accessing an external database blocks. Ideally, you would not write code that blocks for long periods of time. But sometimes you must.

In such a case where some tasks run long, or conversely you have some tasks that must be prioritized for fast execution, then yes, use multiple executor services.

For example, say you have a 16-core machine with not much else running except your Java app. You might have one executor service with a thread pool size of 4 maximum for long-running tasks, one executor service with a thread pool with a size of 7 maximum for many run-of-the-mill tasks, and a third executor service with a thread pool maximum size of 2 for very few tasks that run short but must run quickly. (The numbers here are arbitrary examples, not a recommendation.)

## Other approaches

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371997/single-scheduledexecutorservice-instance-vs-multiple-scheduledexecutorservice-in/71372525#comment126154384_71371997), there are other frameworks for managing concurrency. The `ScheduledExecutorService` discussed here is general purpose.

For example, [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), [Spring](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java%20spring%20concurrency&t=ipad&ia=web), and [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/concurrency/) each have their own concurrency management. Consider using those where approriate to your particular project.

Comment: Really appreciate your suggestion. While, I updated my post with pseudocode and still think maybe let's say when we have fixed pool size of 10, and we have 1000 users using the service at the same time, the service could hang because of lacking available thread. For instance: 10 users already scheduled task1 in about the same time, and they are waiting multiple task2s to be scheduled, finding out no thread available in the pool any more, then, the program hangs.

Comment: By the way, why don't use multiple ScheduledExecutorService instances? Because of the overhead of creating and deleting threads? For Single ScheduledExecutorService instance option, wouldn't that be lots of resource occupation for always maintaining a large number of threads in the fixed sized thread pool? Thanks

Comment: @lightrek Your use of terms is unclear. In that last sentence, do you mean the scheduled executor service is trying to schedule already queued tasks on a CPU for execution, or do you mean calling code is asking the scheduled executor service to queue additional tasks?

Comment: @lightrek Why would you think 3 executor services with 4 threads each be more efficient or effective than one executor service with 12 threads?

Comment: I have updated my post: I mean the 2nd way: calling code is asking to queue additional tasks

Comment: "Why would you think 3 executor services with 4 threads each be more efficient or effective than one executor service with 12 threads?" Because when there is no concurrent users, only 1 executor with 2 treads will be in the system, instead of 12 threads in the system

Comment: @lightrek Threads with no task to execute have virtually no overhead on the CPU.

Comment: Got it! So according to my pseudocode code, program could hang because of lacking available thread right?

Comment: @lightrek (a) Submitting (queueing) more tasks to an executor service will not stop, and will not cause any hangs. You can always hand more tasks to the executor service.

Comment: @lightrek (b) If all threads being used by an executor service to execute tasks are simultaneously blocked for a long time, then all queued tasks must wait, as they cannot be executed until at least one of the currently executing tasks unblocks. Caveat: This is true today, but may *radically* change if and when virtual threads arrive in future versions of Java: Blocked code in a virtual thread in Loom does *not* block the carrier host OS thread executing on the CPU.

Comment: Thank you @Basil, "Submitting (queueing) more tasks to an executor service will not stop" but my problem is the loop of task2 is embeded into the task1. In this case, not sure how I can queue the different type of tasks. What I can think of is using two ScheduledExecutorService s, one for task1 and one for task2